The map $A\colon H^* \to H$ defined as $Af=z$ is bijective and isometric
Let $H$ be a Hilbert space. Let $f\in H^*$ then for the Riesz representation theorem exists a unique $z\in H$ such that $f(x)=\langle x, z \rangle$ for all $x\in H$. This defines an operator $$A\colon H^*\to H\quad\text{by}\quad Af=z.$$
We prove that $A$ is bijective.
First, we prove that $A$ is surjective, indeed let $z\in H$ then if we consider the linear bounded functional $f$ on $H$ defined as $f(x):=\langle x, z \rangle$ we have that $Af=z$, furthermore $A$ is injective indeed if $f_1\ne f_2$, where $f_1, f_2\in H^*$ then from the Riesz representation theorem exists $z_1, z_2\in H$ such that $$f_1(x)=\langle x , z_1\rangle$$ and $$f_2(x)=\langle x , z_2\rangle$$ since $f_1\ne f_2$ we must have $$Af_1=z_1\ne z_2=Af_2.$$
The fact that $A$ is an isometry comes directly from the Riesz representation theorem, in fact if $f\in H^*$, then exists $z\in H$ such that $$f(x)=\langle x , z \rangle$$ for all $x\in H$ and $$\lVert f \rVert =\lVert z\rVert,$$ therefore $$\lVert Af \rVert = \lVert z \rVert = \lVert f \rVert.$$

Is this procedure correct? Also, is it more correct to prove injectivity using the fact that $A$ is an isometry or to do it separately as has been done?


Looks fine to me. I don't think one is "more correct" than the other. Just notice that any isometry is necessarily injective.

One small detail though - you’re proving $A$ is an isometry by showing $|Af| = |f|$. This is fine, but needs some extra justifications, since this fact ($|Af| = |f|$ for all $f$ implies $A$ is an isometry) is usually only applied to linear maps, though being additive is enough. So you should note that $A$ is additive - in fact, linear in case we’re dealing with real Hilbert spaces and conjugate linear for complex Hilbert spaces. Also, once you have additivity, injectivity can be proved by just showing $Af = 0 \Rightarrow f = 0$.

Injectivity, of course, also follows from being an isometry. I concur with Oscar in that there really isn’t such things as one being “more correct” than the other. But if you need to prove isometry anyway, concluding injectivity from that saves you from writing a separate proof for injectivity.
